# Convert base64 image string to IE compliant image, PHP only

Tags: php, image, base64

I'm working on a website in which I get content delivered, and need to work it into a working website.

Due to strict demands I'm not allowed to rely on javascript, and need to have the website working in all most used browsers (and versions). This includes IE8 (and preferably lower too).

Among the delivered content are base64 encoded images. These images are delivered with the image information embedded in front of it. (data:image/png;base64,[image data])

However, since the images are quite big, < IE8 is unable to handle the images. I've been working with the [tutorial from this site](http://danielmclaren.com/node/90) (among others) to get this working, however, I've been unable to so far.

### TL;DR

How can I convert a base64 encoded image to a working format using only PHP? Preferably without having to store the image on the server somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract image type so you can use it as content-type and then simply decode image data:

A simple implementation will look like:

```
  $image = "data:image/png;base64,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";

  $data = explode(";", $image);
  $type = str_replace("data:", "", $data[0]);

  header("Content-type: ".$type);
  echo base64_decode(str_replace("base64,", "", $data[1]));
```

Which will output stackoverflow's logo.

However, some javascript will make things easier, because you could change the image source "*on the fly*" with the php script, if you detect internet explorer. But since you say that is not an option, you should make that match on the server side.

Comment: This works great, thanks. But what exactly do you mean with "you should make that match on the server side"?

Comment: I was referring to check what browser the user has ; if you want to use php for image decoding only for internet explorer, you should check from PHP what browser the user has and change the image "src" accordingly